# What is the difference between function() and ()=> function() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, widget

I have met a problem which is "Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.".

I solve the problem with the following code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      //onTap: press(),  error
      onTap: () => press()
```

But I don't know why.

So, I want to know **What is the difference between function() and ()=> function() in flutter**?

Comment: With `onTap: press()` you are calling the `press` function and passing the return value to `onTap`. With `onTap: () => press()` you are creating an anonymous function, and passing the function to `onTap`. What you should most likely be doing is neither. Instead do `onTap: press` without the parenthesis `()`. This will pass the `press` function rather than the result of calling the `press` function.

Comment: @mmcdon20 that is a beautiful answer. Why did you add it as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @mmcdon20 Thanks for your comment. But There is a new problem (The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable) when I change `press()` to `press`.

Comment: @TAN change the type of `press` from `Function` to `void Function()`. See also https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-signatures-in-function-type-annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's have a look at how these actually work!

Dart has a formal specification documented and you can have a look at it by clicking [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec). A function in Dart has to have a few qualities which are:

1. return type (optional but recommended)
2. name (required)
3. parenthesis right after the name (required)
4. a list of parameters (optional)
5. function body inside curly brackets or a single statement of function body in front of `=>`.

Your question is about point #5. The difference between `{}` and `=>` function body is that the curly brackets allow you to write multiple statements separated with a semi-colon `;` while the second approach shall just be one statement, ended with a single semi-colon `;`.

Let's have a look at a few examples. Here is a simple `log()` function that allows you to log any `Object` instance to the debug console:

```dart
import 'dart:developer' as devtools show log;

extension Log on Object {
  void log() => devtools.log(toString());
}
```

Note how the function has a return type of `void` (point 1), a name called `log` (point 2), no parameters denoted by `()` (point 3 & 4) and a function body which is a single statement with `=>` (point 5).

You could write the same function with curly brackets (point 5) instead of `=>` like so:

```dart
extension Log on Object {
  void log() {
    devtools.log(toString());
  }
}
```

The result of which will be exactly the same as the previous implementation.

Now let's look at another example where your function has a return value and some parameters.

```dart
String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
  return "$firstName $lastName";
}
```

Since this function has simply one statement, the `return` statement and just one semi-colon, it could be re-written as an arrow function like so;

```dart
String fullName(
  String firstName,
  String lastName,
) =>
    "$firstName $lastName";
```

So I would say the unwritten rules are:

1. Use arrow-functions if the body of your function is simple to understand. You could even have multiple lines of code inside an arrow-function's body as long as it's understandable, it's OK to use.
2. Use function bodies with curly-brackets if your function's body is rather complicated, consisting of multiple perhaps un-related pieces of code.

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference between ()=> function and function.

but there is a difference between how you need to call your function.

the first way is this way:

```
onTap: Press,
```

and the other way:

```
onTap: () => Press();
```

well you can get the {} from the function if you call they so: `function();`

and you can get () {} from the function if you only call the name: `function`

Answer (score 0):

```
  onTap: () => press() 
   onTap: (){press();}
```

are the same but (lambda)=>  is used for one line code just short syntex